# searching emails in tire (elastic serach) not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

How to index emails in tire.

i want a full model search including email. The problem is example@gmail.com is not working in search as it as '@' character so it splits up.

this is my query

```
query { terms :_all, params[:query], :minimum_match => 10} if params[:query].present?
```

if i used "include_in_all: false" then how i can include email in query serach or how to send both _all and email in terms query

is there any workable solution  to fully index email without splitting so that it can be included in _all.

tried 'tokenizer' => 'uax_url_email'? but not working . how to set it correctly in rails

Comment: strangely using query { string params[:query][0] } email is searched with @ character included but not (.) character

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/clintongormley/1620128#file-gistfile1-txt-L23) of how to create an index with the _all field using the uax_url_email tokenizer.

Another solution would be to index the email field as not_analyzed.

```
        "email": {
            "type": "multi_field",
            "fields": {
                "email": {"type": "string", "index": "analyzed"},
                "exact": {"type": "string","index": "not_analyzed"}
            }
        }
```

Querying on the "email.exact" term will return the exact email value, without splitting on the "@".

Comment: its not working. here is the gist https://gist.github.com/suras/6326679.   whether i implemented it wrongly. also there is problem with periods(.) in email

Comment: sorry no problem with period in email. following the gist i cant get email in _all working